# UnsatisfiedLinkError while trying to load opencv library

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am getting this error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: file offset for the library "libopencv_java3.so" >= file size: 0 >= 0

when I am trying to link openCV native code with my java code. I tried a number of things but nothing resolved this error. Please suggest me any solutions.

Android.mk

```
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
ifdef OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK
  ifneq ("","$(wildcard $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK)/OpenCV.mk)")
include ${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/OpenCV.mk
  else
include ${OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
endif
else
 include C:/opencv-3.2.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
endif

LOCAL_MODULE := Sample
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(OPTIMISATIONS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
Sample/Sample.cpp
```

build.gradle

```
  defaultConfig
        {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            ndk
                    {
                        moduleName "Sample"
                        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
                    }
        }

externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path '../../../../../opencv-3.2.0-android-sdk/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

The error is occurring at System.loadLibrary("Sample");

Comment: If you would like to consider using CMakeFiles instead of ndkBuild, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821391/unsatisfiedlinkerror-while-trying-to-load-opencv-library, which will lead you to this amazing sample application of calling opencv code from cpp code in an android app -> https://github.com/sengsational/HelloCv

Answer (score 1):

I think that LOCAL_SRC_FILE name you given as ***Sample/Sample.cpp*** is not correct,check SRC_FILE name with full name like ***com_example_app_Sample.cpp*** for your cpp file.

And check ndkBuild path "../../../../../" if this path structure mismatch also the Opencv.mk will not load.

Comment: if I am placing my sample.cpp file within a sample folder, then what should be the SRC_FILE name?

Comment: Actually, the header file will be created by android when you pass the command **-javah -d**(output directory) **-jni**(Generate JNI-style header file (default)) ** -classpath** (Path from which to load classes) in terminal.  Then on the same header file name .cpp file you have to be created. Place Android.mk ,Application.mk , .h and .cpp file in single folder and give that in build.gradle APP_BUILD_SCRIPT and NDK_APPLICATION_MK.  As you asked can use sample folder also..

Answer (score 1):

This error means the system cannot find the compile library (Sample.so). You need to make sure the library is at the right place, and that the system knows where to find it - I would suggest making sure `jniLibs.srcDirs` is set in the build.gradle file. For example, if the library is in 'libs' folder, you put this in the gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
           ...
            jniLibs.srcDirs 'libs'
```